# Terminalから emacsclient を開いた時に ”Waiting for Emacs...”で待機しないようにする

Tags: emacs

ターミナルから `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient` を使ってファイルを開くと  ”Waiting for Emacs...” となってしまうので `&` をつけてバックグラウンドで実行してるのですが、そもそも完全に切り離して使うということは出来るのでしょうか？

バックグラウンドで動かす場合の問題は

- ターミナルのタブを閉じるとファイルが閉じる
- ファイルを閉じるとbg job の終了がターミナル側に通知される

の二点なので上記二点を解消したいと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上の2つの問題は、nohupでおおむねクリアできると思います。

```
$ nohup emacsclient somefile &>/dev/null </dev/null &
```

あるいは、bashならdiswownとか。

```
$ emacsclient somefile &>/dev/null </dev/null &
$ disown %emacsclient
```

zshなら&!とか。

```
% emacsclient somefile &>/dev/null </dev/null &!
```

ちなみに私の場合は、ターミナルから切り離したうえ、Emacsの中からfind-fileしたのと同じように扱いたいので、以下のようなことをシェルスクリプトにして使っています。

```
$ emacsclient -e '(find-file "somefile")'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます `find-file`を呼び出せば同じ動作にできるんですね。`emacs () {/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -e '(find-file "$1")'}`を `.zshrc`に追加したら出来るかと思ったんですが、上手くいきませんでした。やっぱりシェルスクリプトに切り分けたほうがいいんですかね。。

Comment: @ironsand `emacsclient -e "(find-file \"$1\")"` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: `emacs () {/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -e "(find-file \"$1\")";}`のように`$1`をシェルのクォートから外せば（あと末尾の`;`）いけると思います。ただ、`emacs`という関数名は混乱の元なので、`e`とかほかとカブらない名前のほうがよいのではないかと

Comment: うまく行きました、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

`disown` 以外に以下の様な方法もあります。

```sh
$ sh -c 'emacsclient test.txt <&- >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

これで emacsclient プロセスをログインシェルのプロセスグループから切り離す事ができます。一種の daemonize ですね。

```sh
$ pgrep emacscli
4064
$ ps -p 4064 -o pid,ppid,args
  PID  PPID COMMAND
 4064     1 emacsclient test.txt
$ lsof -p 4064
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
emacsclie 4064 nemo  cwd    DIR        8,7    49152  261633 /home/nemo
emacsclie 4064 nemo  rtd    DIR        8,1     4096       2 /
emacsclie 4064 nemo  txt    REG        8,5    22332  661576 /usr/bin/emacsclient
emacsclie 4064 nemo  mem    REG        8,1  1807496  526869 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
emacsclie 4064 nemo  mem    REG        8,1   143792  526864 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
emacsclie 4064 nemo    0u  unix 0x00000000      0t0 1450045 socket
```